# How to send data back to ajax success function?

Tags: node.js, express

I am doing an sql query with do_sql_query function which returns a string when complete. How can I send the string back to my ajax request. I am confused on how to use middleware and the proper callbacks to make it work.

I am using this library to help me do mysql queries: [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

```
app.post('/check', (req,res)=>{

    res.send(do_sql_query())

})

do_sql_query = ()=>{

    var string_to_be_returned;

    mysql_query_function('SELECT * FROM...', (results)=>{

        string_to_be_returned = results.string_Response
    })
    return string_to_be_returned
}
```

Comment: This needs to be a more complete example, right now nobody knows what your do_sql_query does or how it works.  Does it really return a string or does it call a callback? If the latter, that's your problem.

Comment: yes it returns after a callback.

Comment: You still need to provide a more complete code example. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: @Paul I added some more code.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your snippet is that you are returning too early, not waiting for the query to execute.

Any async function (basically something that has a callback argument or similar) you will need to wrap in a promise, or a pattern that you choose, so the route can hold off sending a response until the query has finished.

This is example code only:

```
// promise approach
app.post('/check', (req, res) => {
  do_sql_query()
    .then(value => {
      res.send(value)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // log or something
    })
})

// await approach
app.post('/check', async (req, res) => {
  const value = await do_sql_query()
  res.send(value)
})

do_sql_query = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Not sure of this function, but lets assume it queries the db in an async manner
    //                    missing quote --v
    mysql_query_function('SELECT * FROM...', results => {
      const string_to_be_returned = results.string_Response
      resolve(string_to_be_returned)
    }) // <-- missing in your original snippet
  })
}
```

Comment: I get do_sql_query().then...

is not a function

Comment: The await approach returns undefined.

Comment: If you env isn't correctly set up or on the right version await might not work, stick to the simpler first one for now.

Comment: I cannot get the first one to work at all it gives me an error,

Comment: Its really hard to help if you don't give people here more information. Can you update your question with what you tried and the types of errors you are getting

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris said, the issue is that you're not waiting for the query to execute.  I'm not a fan of Promises myself (unless you can use `await/async`), so I'll show you how to do it w/ regular callbacks.

```
app.post('/check',(req,res)=>{
  do_sql_query((err, results) => {
     if(err) return res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
     return res.send(results);
  });
});

do_sql_query = (callback) = > {
  mysql_query_function('SELECT * FROM...`, (err, results) =>{
    // you don't show how you're defining your mysql_query_function, but most node is error-first callback
    if (err) return callback(err); 
    return callback(null, results);
  }
}
```

Note that anytime  you're doing an asynchronous call, you can't really "return" the results of that call, as those results aren't available until later.  You have to use some form of callback function (whether or not you wrap it in a Promise syntactic sugar) to handle the results of your asynch call.